# Хранение данных админа и пользователей не трубующих регистрации в одной таблице?

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Всем привет. 
Можно ли хранить данные пользователя с ролью "админ", требующего пароль при аутентификации и пользователей, не требующих регистрации и аутентификации. Для этих пользователей необходимо хранить временные данные о том, что они оплатили час тестирования на сайте. Структура таблицы user след.:

1. id (not null)
2. name (not null)
3. pass (null)
4. role (default "guest")
5. status (целочисленные статусы оплаты, например 0,1,2 и т.п.)

Дело в том, чтобы решить указанную задачу я делаю поле pass не обязательным в таблице, но при этом буду его обязательно проверять при аутентификации админа. Верным ли путем я иду? И что вы мне посоветуете?

Спасибо.

Comment: можно табличку ролей отдельно вынести и сделать связующую табличку, тогда можно добавлять больше одной роли пользователю.

Answer (score 1):

Вырисовываются две разные сущности: `users` - авторизованные пользователи системы, как то администратор(ы), тестеры и т.п. в зависимости от роли; и `customers` - клиенты, имеющие совсем другой набор полей и логику обработки. Не нужно пихать их в одну таблицу, вам никогда не понадобятся обе сущности в одной выборке.

Comment: никогда не говори "никогда" а когда понадобится будет уже поздно.

Comment: я так понимаю вы советуете наоборот? В общем хотелось бы узнать ваше мнение.

Comment: да я советую держать одну сущность пользователя и вводить ее в группы, запросом в какой группе пользователь можно всегда узнать админ он или нет. нет никакого смысла разделять этих пользователей по разным таблицам, свойства обычно указываются в связанной таблице. мою правоту доказывает на примере устройство ACL в операционных системах.

Comment: Не до конца понимаю что вы имеете ввиду под группами.(Отдельная таблица групп?)
Что касается варианта таблицы в вопросе, то правильный ли он? Или что там не так?

Comment: всё нормально, если в приложении не предполагается создание ролей из самого приложения.

Answer (score 0):

Пользователи не зарегестрированные это временные пользователи. (Вопрос зачем забивать базу всяких хламом который ненужен, такое нужно в принципе только для статистики посещений, и то оно потом со временем удалится) Представь в мире 7 000 000 000 пользователей (вдруг они зашли на сайт) и если все это перевести в 1 килобайт или больще это же займет нужное место нежными вещами. Так, что администраторы и не за регестрированные пользователи однозначно в разных столбцах должны быть.

Вопрос в другом, если вы пытаетесь сделать одну форму для администраторов и пользователей (зарегестрированных) как вариант можно использовать одну таблицу только указывать уровень пользователя: администратор, модератор, пользователь, подписчик или ктото еще как это реализованно в wordpress

Answer (score -1):

Я бы вам советовал не смешивать одно с другим.

Храните всех пользователей в одной таблице, а в отдельной таблице храните роли. Вход делайте через обычную авторизацию по паролю (или без него, но имхо это не правильно). Проверку на то, является ли пользователь админом, делайте, используя данные из второй таблице. Так меньше шансов, что кто-то сможет получить админский доступ.

А самый надежный способ - иметь админку (клиентскую часть), доступ к которой ограничен списком пользователей, хранящихся в отдельной таблице и никак не связанной с первой.

Comment: а смысл плодить сущности ?

Comment: не могли бы вы дать ссылочки на материалы, где можно подробно про это прочитать?

Comment: Все-таки спрошу: Почему, если роли хранятся в отдельной таблице, то тяжелее получить админский доступ? Почему привязывать роли в той же таблице пользователей хуже?

Comment: Как минимум с точки зрения безопасности.

Если удалось получить доступ к таблице пользователей, то до таблицы с данными админов еще добраться надо будет. А когда оно все в одной - не долго и админ доступ получить.

В общем, вы делайте как угодно, но если будете развивать проект, рано или поздно сами к этому придете :-)

Comment: @Johny и как это сложнее ? Поясните не абстрактно, если я могу сделать "SELECT * FROM USERS" почему я не могу сделать "SELECT * FROM admins" ? IMHO это как раз мнимая безопасность, ложный путь. Как раз гораздо проще отследить права пользователя, если есть один четкий способ получить информацию о них в любом месте кода. Представьте что есть админы,модераторы,менеджеры, пользователи, гости... каждому табличку ?

Comment: @eicto банально. Хотя бы уже потому, что имя таблицы с правами еще узнать нужно, а это уже +5 к сложности)) Но дело даже не столько в безопасности.

Сегодня автор захотел пользователям дать доступ без пароля, завтра решит, что ему нужны будут модераторы, после завтра - расширенные права, а через неделю уже захочет сделать, как вы написали - админы, модераторы, пользователи, гости... При этом на сайте появятся разделы, и автор захочет для каждого раздела назначить отдельные права для каждого пользователя. Вы так и будете все в одной таблице держать? Нет.

Для всех видов прав нужна ОДНА таблица

Comment: Кстати, нет нужды создавать отдельную таблицу для каждой группы, проще сделать таблицу с группами, и таблицу с правами (ACL).

Очень яркой иллюстрацией такого подхода пожалуй будет контроль доступа в форумном движке [`phpBB`][1]

  [1]: https://wiki.phpbb.com/Tables